# append jsp file to div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to append jsp file into div using jQuery.
I want append not load.

**Button:**

```
<input id="add" type="button" class="txtBtn pull-right" value="Add New Asset"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#add').click(function () {
$('#asset').append("<%@include file='load/add.jsp' %> ");
});
```

**jsp body:**

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5" style="padding:25px 0 10px 15px">
            <div  style="width:300px">
                <h2 class="h2" style="margin-top:">Loan Details</h2>
                <select name="type" class="txtBox">
                    <%while (rs.next()) {%>
                    <%if (!rs.getString("states").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("inactive")) {%>
                    <option value=<%=rs.getString("loancode").trim()%>><%=rs.getString("loanname").trim()%></option>
                    <%}%>
                    <%}%>
                </select><br/><br/>
                <ul class="subTopic"><li data-url="load/trailcal.jsp" style="color:#a4a7a9; font-size:12px;">Go to Trial Calculator</li></ul><br/>
                <input type="text" class="txtBox" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" requird/><br/><br/>
                <input type="text" class="txtBox" name="months" placeholder="No. of Months" requird/><br/><br/>
                <input type="button" class="txtBtn pullRight" style="margin-left:5px" value="Cancel">
                <input type="submit" class="txtBtn pullRight" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I append this jsp file to my asset div?

Please tell me how can I do that. if it has any other way please tell me.
I can't edit my jsp body.

Comment: What is the result of your attempt? And avoid wrapping `jsp` file with `body` tag

Comment: nothing happens when click button div is empty

Comment: Debug through console, for any errors like `404` or any `JS` errors

Comment: nothing happens when click button div is empty- isn't that obvious, you are appending some code from the browser that supposed to run on server...the browser does not execute jsp syntax !!

Comment: You can add a ajax call to server to get new HTML and append it, or generate the required HTML from the javascript itself. Still if you need some help with it, you can try posting the add.jsp page..

Comment: SamGhatak thank for help buddy it's worked